# Laravel 5 - Authenticate against two tables

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I'm somewhat new to Laravel and am having issues authenticating users the way I want. I currently have a user table and a companies table in my database.

I have seen numerous examples of authenticating with multiple tables based on whether the user is an admin or not using gaurds, but I looking to authenticate all users in the following way:

1. User's `email` and `password` match (fields in user table)
2. User's `status` is currently active (field in user table)
3. User belongs to company with active `status` (field in companies table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the time I posted this question I've been researching as much as possible and finally ended up with a satisfactory solution. I'm not sure if it is the cleanest way possible, but it works for me. If anyone else can benefit from this, here are the steps I took:

1) I added the following code to `app\User.php` model:

```
   # company / user relationship
   public function company() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'comp_id');
   }

   # determine if company is active
   public function activeCompany() {
      $comp_stat = $this->company()->first(['status'])->toArray();

      return ($comp_stat >= 1) ? true : false;
   }
```

I then modified the handle method in `app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php` with the following:

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
      if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
         if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
         } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
         }
      }

      /* begin modified section */

      if (Auth::check()) {
         # logout if company is inactive
         if (!auth()->user()->activeCompany()) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->guest('login')->with('comp-status-error', true);
         }

         # logout if user is inactive
         if (auth()->user()->status != 1) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->guest('login')->with('user-status-error', true);
         }
      }

      /* end modified section */

      return $next($request);
   }
```

So, technically the user already gets authenticated before the company and user status checks, which is why you have to call `Auth::logout()` manually. This is also the reason why it feels a little "dirty" to me, but again, I couldn't figure out any other way and so I had to do what worked! I encourage anyone to comment if they see a better way to accomplish this.